# Material UI Checkbox (multiple select), state management

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

Does anybody know how can i get an array of all checked items?

What i want is to be able to navigate from one page to another, but all checkboxes need to remain checked. I am going to use localstorage to keep the data, but cant figure out how to get the data (checked items). What do i need to push to LocalStorage?
Also, once i manage to set the data in localstorage, how can i apply it to the dropdown select component to ensure all prev checked boxes are checked again?

Code is exactly the same as here (checkmarks example)

> https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/

I hope my question makes sense.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> What do i need to push to LocalStorage?

Just a name and a boolean value to note if element is checked

> Also, once i manage to set the data in localstorage, how can i apply it to the dropdown select component to ensure all prev checked boxes are checked again?

Definitely a few options here, simple solution would be to run a function inside a useEffect (or even better create a custom hook) to try and get these localstorage values if they exist and set them to local state(custom hook could just return the values).

Other option would be to use Context or another state management library to store these values instead of localstorage and then use hooks provided by these options to have values accessible inside the page component.

Comment: how can i create that array showing which one is checked? i know how to push it to localstorage. Not sure how to create the arrray. and how can i then apply it to my dropdown selector once i extract it from localstorage?

Comment: Wouldn't need to create an array for this necessarily. Just map from the local storage to a local useState<boolean> . That should work well if you have just a few checkboxes. If you have more you could create an object and stringify before setting to localstorage then parse when retrieving it. If you create a small code example I could add to it to show what I mean.